# What does the backslash mean in this regex: if(!/^\s*Production\/Injection Rates/);

Tags: regex, perl

I don't understand what the / in this regular expression means?

```
push(@hds,$_) if(!/^\s*Production\/Injection Rates/);
```

The '\' is not an escape sequence in this context is it? what does / mean? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what the \/ in this regular expression means?

push(@hds,$_) if(!/^\s*Production\/Injection Rates/);

The '\' is not an escape sequence in this context is it? what does \/ mean? Thanks!

Comment: for some reason when i pasted the above in the editor it turns '\/' into '\'?!?!?

Comment: The backslash is escaping the forward slash so it won't be seen as ending the regular expression.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `\` is [the escape character in Perl regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) and elsewhere.  It removes the special meaning from certain characters, and with others it adds special meaning like `\s`.

Since the regex chose to use `/` as its delimiter, any use of it within the regex has to be escaped.  It's hard to read, and is known as [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).  You can avoid this by [choosing a different delimiter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) (and getting rid of the redundant parens).  A balanced delimiter like `{}` or `[]` is easier to read avoids many escaping problems.

```
push(@hds,$_) if !m{^\s*Production/Injection Rates};
```

Answer (score 3):

The `\` says to ignore the slashiness of the slash that follows it.  If you didn't have the backslash preceding it, Perl would think that the slash just before "Injection" was the end of the pattern.

You can rewrite

```
/^\s*Production\/Injection Rates/
```

as

```
m{^\s*Production/Injection Rates}
```

where `m` means "match" and the `{` and `}` are delimiters.  You can also use any other punctuation, like this:

```
m#^\s*Production\/Injection Rates#
```

Answer (score 2):

What this does:

```
if(!/^\s*Production\/Injection Rates/)
```

if () is a normal if statement.
!... proceed if the statement is not true.
/something/ ... Treat the string as regex.

The regex itself `^\s*Production\/Injection Rates` starts:

`^`... Assert, that the position is at the beginning of the string.
`\s*`... Match a whitespace character between zero and unlimmited times, as many times as possible.
`Production` ... Match the string Production
`\/` ... Match the character /
`Injection Rates` ... Match the string Injection Rates